Azure Devops Permissions for Project Collections Administrators: EffectiveAllow is 112
I've written some code which calls az devops security permission list with various parameters to extract the permissions I'm interested in for my various users, so we can report on who has privileged access to specific projects.  The gist of this is:
$myId = 'user.principalname@example.com'
$myOrg = 'https://dev.azure.com/example/'
$myProjectId = 'd1d6f447-cd58-431d-ad22-ee7d6579f6b3'

$projectNamespaceId = '52d39943-cb85-4d7f-8fa8-c6baac873819' # per https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/organizations/security/namespace-reference?view=azure-devops#project-level-namespaces-and-permissions

az devops security permission list --org $myOrg --id $projectNamespaceId --subject $myId | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select-Object token, @{N='EffectiveAllow'; E={
    $dict = $_
    $dict.acesDictionary | 
    Get-Member -type NoteProperty | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $dict.acesDictionary."$($_.Name)".extendedInfo.effectiveAllow
    }
}} | 
Where-Object {$_.token -like "*$myProjectId*"}

This returns:
token                                                                              EffectiveAllow
-----                                                                              --------------
$PROJECT:vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/d1d6f447-cd58-431d-ad22-ee7d6579f6b3  112

I then compare the Effective Allow permissions with the rights I'm interested in for that namespace; i.e. if $effectiveAllow -band 4 returns 4 it shows that the user has access to delete the project.
This works fine for users who have been granted access at the project level, but for those of us who are assigned rights at a higher level than the project itself (e.g. project collection administrators / organization owner / etc) the value returned for effectiveAllow is always 112, implying that we don't have access to delete the project (112 -band 4 returns 0).
Is this a bug in my code/approach?  Or is there a way to find all users who have this permission, including those assigned permissions from a higher scope than the project itself?

According to the doc,

effectiveAllow is the combination of all of the explicit and inherited permissions for this identity on this token. These are the permissions used when determining if a given user has permission to perform an action.

According to my tests:

The default permission combination for the Project Collection Administrators group is 112.
The corresponding number for the "Delete team project" permission is 4.
If you add a user only to PCA, use az devops security permission list or REST API Access Control Lists - Query to check the effectiveAllow of this user in the project namespace. Its value is 112. If you add this user to a project and run the same DevOps CLI or API at this time, the effectiveAllow of the user in the corresponding project/token will change.

So for users only in the PCA group, effectiveAllow is 112 as expected.  112 does not mean that there is no "Delete team project" permission, but a combination of many permissions including "Delete team project" permission.
To check the permissions of users, you can use REST API Permissions Report - Get.

Update
For anyone who wants to learn about effectiveAllow, there is a good blog Azure DevOps Security API demystified for your reference, which has given a detailed explanation.
PCAs are special they have implicit access regardless of their permissions to most of the stuff in ADO. For normal groups your logic would work if they have 112 effectiveAllow it means they do not have delete the project permission. So, for users who are only in PCA, please don't use effectiveAllow to check their permissions. They have all permissions to manage the entire organization.

Thanks @ZiyangLiu-MSFT.  I agree with your comment on effectiveAllow being the result of all permissions inheritted and directly assigned.  Given deny/effectiveDeny is 0 this means there's nothing blocking access, so implies that 112 is the complete set of permissions granted to this user.  112 does not include 4 though, implying that the user does not have access to delete the project; but as a project collection administrator they demonstrably do/can...

You've suggested that 112 (all project permissions) does include 4 (delete project permission); but it's my understanding that this is a bit mask; and there is no overlap between these (i.e. 112 is 01110000; 4 is 00000100; so a bitwise and gives 00000000).  Are these integers not bit masks / have I misunderstood something?

Thank for your analysis. I think my previous analysis of "112 does not mean that there is no "Delete team project" permission, but a combination of many permissions including "Delete team project" permission." is inaccurate.

I found that in addition to Project Collection Administrators, there are other groups whose effectiveAllow is also 112, such as Project Collection Build Administrators, [ProjectName]\Build Administrators. Obviously, by default, the Delete team project of Project Collection Administrators is Allow, and the Delete team project of Project Collection Build Administrators, [ProjectName]\Build Administrators is "Not set". I haven't found any documentation explaining effectiveAllow in detail. I will try to check if I can find more info.

Thank-you @ZiyangLiu-MSFT.  FYI: I'm comfortable that effectiveAllow shows the permissions assigned based on those directly assigned (allow / deny) and those inheritted by membership (effectiveAllow/effectiveDeny of the groups the account is a member of).  The issue I see is that when reporting on a user who isn't assigned to a project, but has full admin via their organisation rights, we don't seem to see their project level rights accurately reflected.  I'm wondering if there's some way to rectify that, or if this is a deliberate omission.

I found a blog, in which the author explains effectiveAllow, especially 112. If so, 112 does not contain "Delete team project". I will try to investigate further and update here if I have any new info.

Thanks @ZiyangLiu-MSFT; confirmed, 112 does not contain 4.  My question is why does someone who does have delete permissions (as they're a project collection administrator giving them full access to all projects) only have a project permission of 112 which doesn't represent the permissions they actually have.  More importantly, is there a way to have az devops security report on the permissions that the user actually has (i.e. when getting permissions assigned to the project to take into account permissions assigned at the org level).

Hi @JohnLBevan, I have confirmed PCAs are special they have implicit access regardless of their permissions to most of the stuff in ADO. For normal groups your logic would work if they have 112 effectiveAllow it means they do not have delete the project permission.

Thanks for your efforts @ZiyangLiu-MSFT

It's my pleasure. I have updated my answer to help others who may have the similar question. Thanks for your good question.
